# Changing the state doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I created two functions that change the state:

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    counters: [
      { id: 1, value: 1 },
      { id: 2, value: 2 },
      { id: 3, value: 0 },
      { id: 4, value: 4 },
    ],
  };

  handleIncrement = (counter) => {
    const counters = [...this.state.counters];
    const index = counters.indexOf(counter);
    counters[index] = { ...counter };
    counters[index].value++;
    this.setState({ counters });
  };
...
```

above code works and change the state, I then created slightly shorter form of above function `handleIncrement` but it didn't work

```
  handleIncrement = (counter) => {
    this.setState({
      counters: this.state.counters[this.state.counters.indexOf(counter)]
        .value++,
    });
```

in above approach I used `setState` and didn't change the state directly. So what is the problem with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "slightly shorter form" does something completely different than the original code. `this.state.counters` is an array of objects. In your first example, you correctly update that array by changing the `value` in one of the objects in the array. In your second example, you replace the array with the result of `this.state.counters[this.state.counters.indexOf(counter)].value++` which is **a number** not an array.

You probably meant to do something like this instead:

```
  handleIncrement = (counter) => {
    this.state.counters[this.state.counters.indexOf(counter)].value++;
    this.setState({
      counters: this.state.counters,
    });
```

This increments the value inside the array and then calls `setState()` by passing in the array for the key `counters`. However, mutating state directly like this is considered poor practice in React because it is easy to forget to call `setState()` to initiate rendering our components. Instead, we create a copy and update the copy and pass that to `setState()`.

Comment: How I replaced the array with a number I called `this.state.counters[this.state.counters.indexOf(counter)].value++` where after finding the index, it is specific which array indexI am targetting and then `.value++` increments the value of that object by one. Can you please correct me

Comment: @BasirPayenda `this.state.counters[this.state.counters.indexOf(counter)].value++` increments the value in the existing array **and returns that number**.

Comment: @BasirPayenda See my latest edit at my guess at what you were trying to do and the reasons why you shouldn't do it that way.

Comment: Thank you, one more thing. In first example, don't you think `counters[index] = { ...counter };` is an extra line of code because we are already playing with a copy of the array and no need to create another copy of its item. Even deleting this line doesn't effect my application

Comment: @BasirPayenda The spread operator is a shallow copy. By this I mean that `const counters = [...this.state.counters];` creates a new array with references to the same objects as in `this.state.counters`. It does **not** copy those objects. This is why we need to do `counters[index] = { ...counter };`. This copies the keys and values of the object to be updated. Note that this is again a shallow copy. If any of those values were lists or objects, we would get references to those same lists or objects, not copies of them.